# hashCode() and equals() with Class<T>

Tags: java, class, equals, hashcode

I've bumped into an unexpected problem with `equals()` and `hashcode()`.

Eclipse refused to generate them properly, because `Class` does not override them. Oh uh.

So I had to compare them by `.getName()` result, but it is ugly.

```
private Class<T> clientClass;

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + clientClass.getName().hashCode();
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof MessageChannel)) return false;

    MessageChannel<?, ?> other = (MessageChannel<?, ?>) obj;

    if (!clientClass.getName().equals(other.clientClass.getName())) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note that T is a parameter.

How to do this correctly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "because Class does not override them"?

Comment: class `Class` does not define equals nor hashcode, i think it's pretty clear what that means.

Comment: Why not use the *non-overridden* Class.equals/hashCode? It doesn't matter what Eclipse says, *identity* is a sane comparison of `Class<T>` (e.g. there is/should only be one instance of `Class<T>` for any `T`.

Comment: Class doesn't need to override them for you to be able to call them, since these methods are defined on Object.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it possible that I get two different instances of Class representing the same class? Object just uses `==` on them afaik. Perhaps with two classloaders or whatever, I'm not that familiar with this reflection magic.

Comment: @MightyPork I'm fairly certain that's not possible, but if that is the question, ask it directly: "Is it correct/safe to use identity comparisons on Class<T>?" or "How many Class instances are there for a particular type?" or ..

Comment: Fine, I'll risk that I guess. Thanks

Comment: It is possible, if you have 2 classloaders loading the same class. But that's highly improbable, and you probably don't want your objects to be equal anyway if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to do something special to deal `equals` and `hashcode` for Class.  The current behaviour (inherited from `Object`) is semantically correct.  (If Eclipse is warning you otherwise, ignore it.  The warnings are incorrect.)

> Isn't it possible that I get two different instances of Class representing the same class? Object just uses == on them afaik. Perhaps with two classloaders or whatever, I'm not that familiar with this reflection magic.

Yes it is possible.

But in that case, they are in fact *different classes* from the perspective of the Java type system. (See JLS [4.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4) for details.)  And hence, you *should* be treating them as not equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do following

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
  return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(that, this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

You can read more about this nice builder on 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/package-summary.html

Comment: I'm not going to bloat my project with Apache commons.

Comment: Well then I suggest that you take a look at http://projectlombok.org/
A really nice project that solve this project, without bloat your project with Apache commons.